# Como construir um objeto filho usando o construtor do objeto pai?

Tags: c, c++, herança, construtor, polimorfismo

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de um objeto filho usar o construtor do objeto pai ao ser construído (sem a necessidade de criar um construtor explícito no objeto filho). Por exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Pai
{
public:
    Pai(const std::string& msg) {
        std::cout << msg << std::endl;
    }
};



class Filho : public Pai
{
public:

    // usa o construtor da classe pai de forma implícita

};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // era pra funcionar :(
    Filho obj_filho("hello, world");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Após dar uma pesquisada, descobri que para usar o construtor de uma classe base para construir a classe derivada, eu posso usar a palavra-chave "using":

```
class Filho : public Pai
{
public:
    // herda o construtor da classe Pai
    using Pai::Pai;
};
```